# Concatenate formatted string in macro

Tags: android, c, macros

I am doing some algorithm development on android platform. I want to modify my past developer's code and add keyword to it, since he has had put so many useful log info in the code. But I want to grep a new keyword by `logcat` to see all the useful log I want.

1.The idea is to use: `adb logcat` | grep 'keyword'  to see the log file. For example the keyword can be a person's name James.

2.The past developer remode the ALOGE in the header file like this. and he add many LOG_ACD in the .c file.

```
#define LOG_ACD(fmt, args...) if (acd->stats_debug_mask & STATS_DEBUG_MASK_ACD_LOG) ALOGE(fmt, ##args)
```

example in c is LOG_AcD("%s: acd_enable %d, monitor %d,  freq %d, afd_state %d, acd_atb %d",
    **func**, output->acd_enable, output->acd_monitor, 
    output->freq, output->acd_state, output->acd_atb);

3.How can I add the keyword to the above line of code to force each line of LOG_ACD in .c file has my new keyword? The interesting part for me is the ALOGE itself is not a string, the format string will be generated in the .c file.

I hope I describe the problem clearly. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the format string will be gerenated in the C file. I think you don't mean what you say.

For `printf`-like functions, it is common to specify a literal format string. (The format string is the string with all the format specifiers like `%d`. A literal string is a zero-terminated string constant between double quotes.) If that is the case (and your example backs this assumption), you can use string-literal concatenation:

```
#define LOG_ACD(fmt, args...) ALOGE("ACD: " fmt, ##args)
```

Two adjacent string literals are compiled as one, e.g. `"A" "B"` is essentially the same as `"AB"`. The macro will generate a compile-time error when the format string is not a literal, but, as said above, that's unusual.

Comment: Thank you. I mean I search some solution on-line. but they are for combination of two 'plain' strings. I tried your method, which will pass make by mm, but I can not grep the keyword. I will try it one more time in case that I did not do it right. Thanks man

Comment: grep will not get the added keyword

Comment: All log entries written by that macro - I've left out the condition for clarity - should prepend theoutput with "ACD: ", e.g. `LOG_ACD("x == %d", x)` should print something like "ACD: x == 9", which should enable you to grep for "ACD".

Comment: Your solution is the "ACD: " will be added to the fmt and become a part of fmt. I just pushed the file to my phone twice. The grep cannot  find the keyword.

Comment: Have you looked into the log file in an editor, without grepping? What do you see?

Comment: Hey M, it works for me. I edited the wrong line. The header file is a large one. Thank you so much.